# Bolding specific text inside a variable with PHP?

Tags: php, fonts

I am trying to modify a string in my project. The string I am modifying contains a paragraph that the user enters, and I am trying to replace specific occurrences of words(like NOUN/VERB), with the user entered nouns and verbs. Everything is working perfectly, except I am attempting to make the font of the user entered nouns and verbs in bold font, however I cannot figure out where to bold the text. Any suggestions or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php

//Variables
$stringFirstVerb = $_POST["stringFirstVerb"];             
$stringSecondVerb = $_POST["stringSecondVerb"];           
$stringThirdVerb = $_POST["stringThirdVerb"];             
$stringFirstNoun = $_POST["stringFirstNoun"];        
$stringSecondNoun = $_POST["stringSecondNoun"];             
$stringThirdNoun = $_POST["stringThirdNoun"];            
$stringFirstAdj = $_POST["stringFirstAdj"];     
$stringSecondAdj = $_POST["stringSecondAdj"];           
$stringThirdAdj = $_POST["stringThirdAdj"];             
$stringParagraph = $_POST["stringParagraph"];        
$intNounCount = 0;
$intVerbCount= 0;
$intAdjCount = 0;

//check for user input
$stringNewStr = implode("",array($stringFirstVerb,$stringSecondVerb,$stringThirdVerb,$stringFirstNoun,$stringSecondNoun,$stringThirdNoun,$stringFirstAdj,$stringSecondAdj,$stringThirdAdj));   //consolidates every replacable word into a single string

if( strpos($stringNewStr, ' ' ) !== false ){
echo "No spaces allowed in any Verbs, Nouns, or Adj's";
echo "<br>";
echo "<a href='project1.html'>Link to previous Page</a>";
}


else if( strpos($stringNewStr, '!' ) !== false  || strpos($stringNewStr, '.' ) !== false ||
strpos($stringNewStr, ';' ) !== false || 
strpos($stringNewStr, ':' ) !== false ||
strpos($stringNewStr, ',' ) !== false){
echo "No punctuation allowed in any Verbs, Nouns, or Adj's";
echo "<br>";
echo "<a href='project1.html'>Link to previous Page</a>";
}




else                    //if input is valid, moves onto next step

//checkif paragraph contains 3 of each word types
{

$stringNoun = "NOUN";
$intNounCount = (substr_count($stringParagraph, $stringNoun));

$stringVerb = "VERB";
$intVerbCount = (substr_count($stringParagraph, $stringVerb));

$stringAdj = "ADJ";
$intAdjCount = (substr_count($stringParagraph, $stringAdj));

echo $intNounCount;
echo $intAdjCount;
echo $intVerbCount;

if ($intNounCount !== 3 || $intVerbCount !== 3 || $intAdjCount !== 3){
echo "the paragraph must contain the words VERB, NOUN, and ADJ three times each!";
echo "<br>";
echo "<a href='project1.html'>Link to 
previous Page</a>";
}

else    //if conditions are met
{

//replace user entered words
$stringParagraph = str_replace('VERB1', 
$stringFirstVerb, $stringParagraph);    
//replaces the first verb in the paragraph with user entered verb in bold text
$stringParagraph = str_replace('VERB2', 
$stringSecondVerb, $stringParagraph);     
//replaces the second verb in the paragraph with user entered verb in bold text
$stringParagraph = str_replace('VERB3', 
$stringThirdVerb, $stringParagraph);     
//replaces the third verb in the paragraph with user entered verb in bold text
$stringParagraph = str_replace('NOUN1', 
$stringFirstNoun, $stringParagraph);     
//replaces the first verb in the paragraph with user entered verb in bold text
$stringParagraph = str_replace('NOUN2', 
$stringSecondNoun, $stringParagraph);     
//replaces the second verb in the paragraph with user entered verb in bold text
$stringParagraph = str_replace('NOUN3', 
$stringThirdNoun, $stringParagraph);     
//replaces the third verb in the paragraph with user entered verb in bold text
$stringParagraph = str_replace('ADJ1', 
$stringFirstAdj, $stringParagraph);     
//replaces the first verb in the paragraph with user entered verb in bold text
$stringParagraph = str_replace('ADJ2', 
$stringSecondAdj, $stringParagraph);     
//replaces the second verb in the paragraph with user entered verb in bold text
$stringParagraph = str_replace('ADJ3', 
$stringThirdAdj, $stringParagraph);     
//replaces the third verb in the paragraph with user entered verb in bold text

echo $stringParagraph;          //outputs modified paragraph

echo "<br><br><br>";
echo "<a href='project1.html'>Enter another Madlibs!</a>";      //button to html page


//write paragraph to a txt file
$results = "results.txt";
//$resultsLink = fopen($results, 'a');
$stringFileParagraph = $stringParagraph;
//fwrite($resultsLink, 
$stringFileParagraph);
//fclose($resultsLink);

file_put_contents($results, 
$stringFileParagraph, FILE_APPEND); 
//saves the contents to a textfile, if textfile exists new entry will be added




}//end second else

}//end first else






?>
```

I have been attempting to modify the strings inside $stringParagraph with the str_replace command but have not been successful. In short all I am trying to do is display the contents of $stringParagraph to the user, with the contents of $stringFirstNoun/SecondNoun being bold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$stringParagraph = str_replace('VERB2', 
'<span class="highlight">' . $stringSecondVerb . '</span>', $stringParagraph);
```

Then the highlight class can style the replacements with whatever CSS you want, making it easy to change in the future

Also you it's probably worth doing some sanitising on your variables, else you might as well have just used the post array directly.  As you're not doing any database work with this code your main risk is someone trying to embed a hidden script, you should take a look at strip_tags, or a preg_replace to clean out unwanted/potentially dangerous tags.

And just as a thought, could you instead of having a long list of variables build a key => value array, then you could loop through the array ( or even better write a function) to replace your strings which would make it more easily expandable should you add in extra inputs (e.g verb4).  Unless you're using these variables somewhere outside of the code dislayed here?

Comment: I applied the code to my lines, and they remained unaffected. I will look into span class more to see if I can get this working. Thank you for your suggestion.  Update: code is working great, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Just be to clear, the span is a html tag and the class is for CSS, I'm working on the assumption you know how to use CSS and CSS classes etc - the highlight class is an arbitrary name for the example and won't automatically do anything. if that's not the case then do say so and I will update the answer

Answer (score -1):

When you are replacing your tokens, such as `VERB1` with the corresponding values, you want to wrap that value in bold tags. So:

```
$stringParagraph = str_replace('VERB1', 
$stringFirstVerb, $stringParagraph);
```

Should be:

```
$stringParagraph = str_replace('VERB1', 
"<b>".$stringFirstVerb."</b>", $stringParagraph);
```

Comment: Note: According to the HTML 5 specification, the <b> tag should be used as a LAST resort when no other tag is more appropriate. The HTML 5 specification states that headings should be denoted with the <h1> to <h6> tags, emphasized text should be denoted with the <em> tag, important text should be denoted with the <strong> tag, and marked/highlighted text should use the <mark> tag.  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_b.asp

Answer (score -1):

I really don't really understand your question?
Maybe you want to make an action if the user enters a noun / verb in lowercase the action goes well, but if the user enters a noun / verb with one of the letters inputted by the user the uppercase action fails??

You can use the **strtolower()** function, before you combine all the variables./

try this:

```
$stringNewStr = implode ("", array ($ stringFirstVerb, $ stringSecondVerb, $stringThirdVerb, $ stringFirstNoun, $ stringSecondNoun, $ stringThirdNoun, $stringFirstAdj, $ stringSecondAdj, $ stringSecondAdj, $ stringThirdAdj));

$stringNewStrLow = strtolower($stringNewStr);
```

Comment: Your variables are not valid there can not be a space between `$` and the variable name. Also, please use the newer short hand `[]` for arrays in place of `array()`.